# cdi bean injection for initialization code

Tags: cdi, wildfly-swarm, deltaspike

I have a bean configured which have some initialization logic. I have annotated this bean using @ApplicationScoped annotation. But somehow, cdi is not picking this bean.

beans.xml content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

Bean file:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Initializer{

    @Inject @ConfigProperty(name = "app.name")
    private String appName;
    @Inject @ConfigProperty(name = "app.token")
    private String appToken;
    @Inject @ConfigProperty(name = "app.version")
    private String appVersion;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       System.out.println("flow should come here....); //but this line does not execute.
    }
}
```

Code to read config file:

```
@Exclude
public class ConfigurationFile implements PropertyFileConfig {

    @Override
    public String getPropertyFileName() {
    String env = Util.getEnv();
    switch (env) {
    case "dev":
    case "uat":
    case "prod":
        return "config/" + env + "/default.properties";
    default:
        return "config/default.properties";
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOptional() {
    return false;
    }
}
```

I am using:
cdiL: for dependency injection,
apache-deltaspike: for reading config file. 
wildfly-swarm: server

Comment: Just adding a scope does not make it a managed bean. Add a `@Named` annotation

Comment: I'm not sure what cdiL is, so hard to comment on what the issue might be

Comment: Are you actually using that bean somehow? Weld (CDI impl you are using) is lazily initiated and will not create the actual bean until needed, e.g. it won't call `@PostConstruct` - add some dummy method on that bean and try invoking it.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Comment: At Kukeltje: That's not right. The @Named is just optional to access the bean via EL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution to this problem.

Issue is solved by changing the method declaration as follows:

```
public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object init) {
//................code logic here................
}
```